# How to change alignments in LibGDX Table?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a table in **libgdx** that represents an onscreen controller for a game. Two of the buttons will be on the left and one will be on the right. When I try to get the table to switch to the right side, it still ends up on the left side.

```
public class Controller {

    Viewport viewport;
    Stage stage;

    boolean upPressed;
    boolean downPressed;
    boolean leftPressed;
    boolean rightPressed;

    OrthographicCamera cam;

    public Controller(){
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(800, 480, cam);

        stage = new Stage(viewport, OverlayDemo.batch);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Table table = new Table();
        table.left().bottom();

        Image upImage = new Image(new Texture("flatDark25.png"));
        upImage.setSize(80, 80);
        upImage.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                upPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                upPressed = false;
            }
        });

        Image leftImage = new Image(new Texture("flatDark23.png"));
        leftImage.setSize(80, 80);
        leftImage.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                leftPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                leftPressed = false;
            }
        });

        Image rightImage = new Image(new Texture("flatDark24.png"));
        rightImage.setSize(80, 80);
        rightImage.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Right pressed");
                rightPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
        });

        table.bottom().left();
        table.pad(10);
        table.add(leftImage).size(leftImage.getWidth(), leftImage.getHeight());
        table.add(rightImage).padLeft(20).size(rightImage.getWidth(), rightImage.getHeight());

        table.bottom().right();
        table.pad(10);
        table.add(upImage).size(upImage.getWidth(), upImage.getHeight());

        table.pack();

        stage.addActor(table);
    }


    public void draw(){
        stage.draw();
    }

    public boolean isUpPressed() {
        return upPressed;
    }

    public boolean isRightPressed() {
        return rightPressed;
    }

    public boolean isDownPressed() {
        return downPressed;
    }

    public boolean isLeftPressed() {
        return leftPressed;
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height){
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
}
```

In the part where I call `.bottom().right()`, it should switch alignments to the right. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It is unclear to me whether the above code is all in the same method or not. You should edit your question to clarify this by showing the class and method or methods which contain this code.

Comment: It is in the same method

Comment: What class contains this code?

Comment: A controller class that handles the input; the table is used to layout the buttons on the screen

Comment: Please show that in your code. Also explain more about what you expect the code to accomplish. I am unclear on what result you want here.

Comment: I want the upImage to be right aligned while the leftImage and rightImage to stay left aligned

Comment: Within the table cell, you mean?

Comment: When you call `table.bottom().left();` or `table.bottom().right();`, you are aligning the logical table within the bounds of the complete table. I can't tell what you are trying to make it look like, even from your comments, but calling these various alignment methods on the table itself is simply setting parameters on the table. Only the last ones called will stick.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are aligning the `Table` itself and not the underlying `Cell`s. The align method should be called after the `add(actor)` so your code should look something like this

```
table.add(leftImage).size(leftImage.getWidth(), leftImage.getHeight()).pad(10).bottom().left();
table.add(rightImage).padLeft(20).size(rightImage.getWidth(), rightImage.getHeight()).pad(10).bottom().left();

table.add(upImage).size(upImage.getWidth(), upImage.getHeight()).pad(10).bottom().right();

table.pack();

stage.addActor(table);
```

I would also advise you to call `table.setFillParent(true)`, because it seems like it is the root table.
For further reading on Tables you can look into the [libGDX Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table).